# Searching for a solution to set up a reverse proxy for game servers

Tags: networking, iptables, proxy, reverse-proxy

I run a game server on my dedicated box in country A, which runs Linux and communicates with its clients using UDP.

The server has players from both inside and outside Country A. Players within Country A have good connections (low ping and no packet loss) to the game server. But most players outside Country A have bad connections (high ping and high packet loss) to the game server.

I have a VPS in country B, which also runs Linux and has good connections to both the game server and players **outside** Country A.

What I want to achieve is players **outside** Country A connect to the game server via the VPS while players **inside** Country A to connect directly to the game server.

Is the VPS acting as a reverse proxy in this scenario?

Is this goal acheivable using iptables? If yes, could someone give me a step-by-step instruction?

Answer (score 1):

No, the VPS is acting as a forward proxy, or just a regular proxy, in this case. You can achieve this using `iptables`, but there are probably some easier solutions available. Using `iptables`, you would want to set up DNAT and SNAT rules in your FORWARD table - no I don't have specific step-by-step instructions, but it shouldn't be too difficult for you to figure out the individual rules you need to add.